# calling BIF map(min()) - what happens?

Tags: python, function, min

I have two lists:

`a,b=[1,2],[33,44]`

I want to explore both their minimum. But

```
>>> min(a,b)
```

returns  `[1, 2]` as `min()`

> With more than one argument, return the smallest of the arguments.

Same happens if I use `map()` as 
    `map(min,a,b)`

is mostly equivalent to:

```
[f(x1, x2) for x1, x2 in zip(sequence1, sequence2)]
```

as already stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672172/how-to-use-python-map-and-other-functional-tools).

```
>>> map(min,[a,b])
[1, 33]
```

gives me what I want but I don't really understand why. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in Python [`map` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map):

> Apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the results. **If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel**.

When you call:

```
map(min, a, b)
```

You are actually passing *two* iterables to `map`. This successively calls `min(1, 33)` and `min(2, 44)`, thus returning `[1, 2]`.

However, in:

```
map(min, [a, b])
```

There is a single iterable, and `map` calls `min` on each element of the sequence:

- First calling `min([1, 2])` which yields `1`
- Then calling `min([33, 44])` which yields `33`

The result, as expected, is `[1, 33]`.

Comment: Reading your answer this makes perfectly sense. Thanks for explaining. Is `map()` actually working like a generator then?

Comment: @larsvegas `map()` returns list in python 2.x and in python 3.x it returns a `map object`, which is a generator.