# Map function and input function parameters

Tags: python, map-function

Here's a stupid example:

```
def add_x_to_input(x,k):
   return x + k

myList = [1,2,3,4]
myNewList = map(add_x_to_input???, myList)
```

How do I specify the parameter `x` of `add_x_to_input`, when I give it as input function to `map`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672172/how-to-use-python-map-and-other-functional-tools

Comment: yes. In short, I want to be able to parameterize that function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial
map(partial(add_x_to_input, some_value_for_x), myList)
```

or you could use a [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) (an anonymous, in-line function):

```
map(lambda k: add_x_to_input(some_value_for_x, k), myList)
```

or you could define an explicit new function:

```
def wrapping_function(k):
    return add_x_to_input(some_value_for_x, k)

map(wrapping_function, myList)
```

If you are after sheer speed, the `functools.partial()` approach wins that hands-down; it is implemented in C code and avoids an extra Python stack push:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> L = range(10)
>>> def foo(a, b): pass
... 
>>> def p(b): return foo(1, b)
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('map(p, L)', 'from __main__ import foo, L; from functools import partial; p = partial(foo, 1)')
3.0008959770202637
>>> timeit.timeit('map(p, L)', 'from __main__ import foo, L; p = lambda b: foo(1, b)')
3.8707590103149414
>>> timeit.timeit('map(p, L)', 'from __main__ import foo, L, p')
3.9136409759521484
```

Comment: I like the lambda function solution. Should I worry about any possible impact on speed, compared to a plain call to `map`?

Comment: @RickyRobinson: There is some indirection, so all three options will cost you some speed. All three will have close to the same overhead though.

Comment: Ok. The thing is I'm trying to convert all my for loops into `map` calls, so I wouldn't wanna go back to the previous situation in terms of speed.

Comment: @RickyRobinson: I'd try out different approaches, it could be that `partial()` is going to be faster (it's implemented in C), for example, saving a stack push.

Comment: @RickyRobinson: I added a speed comparison for your enjoyment; `functools.partial()` is going to be closest to calling the wrapped function directly.

Answer (score 2):

```
def add_x_to_input(x,k):
   return x + k

myList = [1,2,3,4]
x = 5
myNewList = map(lambda k:add_x_to_input(x,k), myList)
```

or just:

```
myNewList = [x+k for k in myList]
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a closure:

```
In [61]: def add_x_to_input(x,k):
    ...:    return x + k

In [62]: def add_1(x):
    ...:     return add_x_to_input(x,1)

In [63]: add_1(1)
Out[63]: 2

In [64]: list = [1,2,3]

In [65]: map(add_1, list)
Out[65]: [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: OK, I wanted to avoid having to write a function for each parameter in use, but if there is no other way, then OK. :)