# Is there a way to add a number to the first part of a tuple in a list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

So i have a list for example:

```
a = [(1,2),(2,3)]
```

i was wondering if there is a way to add a number lets say 2 to the seccond part of the tuple so it looks like

```
a = [(1,4),(2,5)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> a = [(1,2),(2,3)]
>>> [(x, y+2) for x,y in a]
[(1, 4), (2, 5)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've already got answers about how to do this with `tuple`. But you should consider whether an immutable type is the right choice if you know you'll be modifiying them

For comparison if you have a `list` of `list`, it's a lot less work (cpu wise)

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[2,3]]
>>> for i in a: i[1] += 2
... 
>>> a
[[1, 4], [2, 5]]
```

since you don't need to create a whole new data structure and copy the values into it to make the modification

If numpy arrays turn out to be a suitable choice, it's even easier to broadcast the addition

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([(1,2), (2,3)])
>>> a[:, -1] += 2
>>> a
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
a = [(1,2), (2,3)]
a = [(x, y+2) for (x,y) in a]
```

gives

```
a = [(1,4),(2,5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the map function to yield a new tuple with the desired values. This post discusses the map function. You can also google map functional programming.

[Using python map and other functional tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672172/how-to-use-python-map-and-other-functional-tools)

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are immutable, so once they are created, they cannot be modified. However, you can replace a tuple in a list with a different tuple, with values based on the first one, like this:

```
for i, tup in enumerate(list_of_tuples):
    list_of_tuples[i] = (tup[0], tup[1]+2)
```

An alternative solution is to create a new list with values based on the tuples in the original list. Here's a list comprehension that creates a new list of tuples by 2 to the second value of each tuple in an existing list:

```
new_list = [(a, b+2) for a, b in orig_list]
```