# Python: Processing each row independently using map function

Tags: python, list, dictionary, row, element

Assuming the list:

```
[[2,4,0,8],[0,2,4,8],[8,0,2,4],[8,2,0,4]]
```

Hi guys, how do I use map function to process each element inside the row of the list?

For e.g. if I want to add the pairs of each list:

```
[[6,0,8,0],[2,0,12,0],[8,0,6,0],[10,0,4,0]]
```

Basically I don't know how to use the map function very well, never find very useful article about mapping. Appreciate if I can get some links. Thanks!!!

Comment: "I want to add the pairs of each list" -- what exactly means? Can you give an example. How do you to make pairs?

Comment: Actually main thing is I want to know how to manipulate the elements in rows. Which mean I can also add all the element in for e.g. [2,4,0,8] making it into [14,0,0,0].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what is your function actually.

**First:** If the function say `f` accepts "list as complete row" then you can use:

```
m = [[6, 0, 8, 0], [2, 0, 12, 0], [8, 0, 6, 0], [10, 0, 4, 0]]
map(f, m)
```

**Second:** If function `f` accepts each element then you need to call nested `map()`, something like as below:

```
map(lambda r: map(f, r), m)
```

For this, you could also use list compression:

```
[map(f, r) for r in m] # I prefer this
```

There are other tricks also, like you can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial) Check this [example](http://ideone.com/dvi16G).

```
from functools import partial
newf = partial(map, f)
map(newf, m)
```

**Edit** as response to comment:

> Actually main thing is I want to know how to manipulate the elements in rows. Which mean I can also add all the element in for e.g. `[2, 4, 0, 8]` making it into `[14, 0, 0, 0]`.

First, I have doubt why you wants to convert a list `[2, 4, 0, 8]` into `[14, 0, 0, 0]`, why not to output just `14` — the sum, check if you can improve your algorithm/design of your program.

Anyways, in Python we have sum() function, read documentation [`sum(iterable[, start])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum), example (read comments):

```
>>> row =  [2,4,0,8] 
>>> sum(row)  # just outputs sum of all elements, in rows
14
```

So if you wants to pass "a list of lists" like `m` (you posted in question) then you can use `map(sum, m)` see below:

```
>>> m = [[6, 0, 8, 0], [2, 0, 12, 0], [8, 0, 6, 0], [10, 0, 4, 0]]
>>> map(sum, m)  # call sum for each row (a list) in `m`
[14, 14, 14, 14] # sum of all individual list's elements
```

But if you wants to make a list like you asked then you can use `+` (list concatenate) operator with sum as below:

```
>>> row =  [2, 4, 0, 8] 
>>> [sum(row)] + [0,] * (len(row) -1 )
[14, 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```

To understand this code piece:

1. `[sum(row)]`  means list of single element that is sum of row — `[14]`.
2. `[0,] * (len(row) -1 )` makes a list of zeros of length one less then number of elements in row, check below code example:

   ```
    >>> row =  [2, 4, 0, 8]   # 4 elements 
    >>> [0,] * (len(row) -1 )
    [0, 0, 0] # 3 zeros
    >>>
   ```

   The * operator similarly can be applied to tuple, string also.
3. So from above, I make two separate lists and add + both finally as below:

   ```
   >>> row =  [2, 4, 0, 8] 
   >>> [sum(row)] + [0,] * (len(row) -1 )
   [14, 0, 0, 0]  # that is what you wants
   ```

Now, you wants to execute `[sum(row)] + [0,] * (len(row) -1 )` expression for each row<sub>i</sub> ∈ m, then you can use lambda expression with `map()` as below:

```
>>> map(lambda row: [sum(row)] + [0,] * (len(row) -1 ), m)
[[14, 0, 0, 0], [14, 0, 0, 0], [14, 0, 0, 0], [14, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Better is to lambda expression a name:

```
>>> f = lambda r: [sum(r)] + [0,] * (len(r) -1 )
>>> f(row)
[14, 0, 0, 0]
```

then use `map()`:

```
>>> map(f, m)
[[14, 0, 0, 0], [14, 0, 0, 0], [14, 0, 0, 0], [14, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Just as I suggested in first few lines in my answer. Again you can use list compression here in place of calling map() as:

```
>>> [f(r) for r in m]
```

Comment: On quick search I could have find this ["How to Use python map and other functional tools"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672172/how-to-use-python-map-and-other-functional-tools)

Comment: @user3498996 You welcome, If you wants to improve Python (as you asked you need resources) I would suggest you daily read [4-5 Q&As, from hot list](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/hot) and regularly [High voted answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=votes&pageSize=50). Best book is I think Learning Python - but it is time taking.

Answer (score 1):

This is the not the cleanest solution, but it shows you how to use `map` on lists of lists.

However you want to define the `addPairs` method, it has to take a `list` as input, and return a `list`.

```
lst = [[2,4,0,8],[0,2,4,8],[8,0,2,4],[8,2,0,4]]

def addPairs(y):
   out = []
   for i in xrange(len(y)):
      if i % 2 == 0:
        out.append(y[i] + y[i+1])
      else: out.append(0)
   return out


output = map(addPairs, lst)
print output
```

Answer (score 1):

If the sub-arrays are fixed to 4 items, then for each item `[a, b, c, d]` in the input array, you want to output an item `[a+b, 0, c+d, 0]`

Using `map`, you can do this using;

```
map(lambda x: [x[0]+x[1], 0, x[2]+x[3], 0], input_array)
```

Comment: That seems very _limiting_. What if you had 1000 elements in each list.

Comment: @sshashank124 Then yes, you'd use another method. This was mainly meant as a very simple example of mapping one simple value to another to show how map works.

Comment: sir why delete your answer in my question

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973766/understanding-the-map-function-python) post.  The best answer there has some very good information.

I would also look at [this] page on lambda functions since whenever i do use map i tend to use lambda as well...

as for the example you posted...

I wouldn't use mapping for this.  I would definitely prefer to use list comprehensions here I think

```
v=[[sum(i[0:2]),0,sum(i[2:]),0] for i in m]
```