# What’s the function of map()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What’s is the function of map() in my code?

```
squares = list(map(lambda x: x**2, range(10)))
```

Comment: Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

Comment: other than the above mentioned docs, try searching questions about the map() function, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672172/using-python-map-and-other-functional-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple terms,

> map executes the function for the given iterable objects

**Definition:**

> map() function is used to apply a function on all the elements of
>   specified iterable and return map object. Python map object is an
>   iterator, so we can iterate over its elements

In your code,

```
squares = list(map(lambda x: x**2, range(10)))
```

**Function** : `lambda x: x**2`

**Ex:**

```
f = lambda x: x**2
```

**f(2)** gives **4** as output

**Iterable object** : `range(10)`

**Ex:**
it creates a iterable object of range 0 to 9

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

What map doing is, calling the function for all elements in range,

like `f(0), f(1), ... , f(9)`

and then You have created the list with output elements.

Answer (score 1):

That code (`squares = list(map(lambda x: x**2, range(10)))`) is strictly similar to:

```
f = lambda x: x**2
squares = []
for x in range(10):
    squares.append(f(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

The map function is function used to apply on elements specified in the iteration. In your example, the iteration is range(10) (0 to 9) and applying the function square of each number from 0 to 9. Map returns a list of squared numbers from 0 to 81.

Answer (score 0):

It is a [map-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)):

> In many programming languages, map is the name of a higher-order function that applies a given function to each element of a functor, e.g. a list, returning a list of results in the same order. It is often called apply-to-all when considered in functional form.

From [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results. If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel. With multiple iterables, the iterator stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted. For cases where the function inputs are already arranged into argument tuples, see itertools.starmap().

In simple words, it is a function that applies a given function to each element of given container:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
l = lambda x: x + 10
list(map(l, a))
```

will return:

> `[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]`