# Comparing pandas dataframe values to a dictionary key, then inserting the values in that dictionary into new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Relatively new python/pandas user here. I have a dataframe with many thousand values in column A, indexed to Account_num.

```
ID_num  A
A300    37
B400    82
T500    10
...     ...
```

There is another dataframe that has around 300 values in column M. Every value in column N shows up in column A in the first dataframe, each hundreds/thousands of times. For each of these values, there is a mean, median, and mode.

```
M   Mean  Median  Mode
99  2.3   7.0     9.9
37  3.6   6.6     0.2
10  4.1   4.2     8.1
82  1.9   7.7     5.0
... ...   ...     ...
```

The output I'm looking for would be something like this:

```
ID_num  A   Mean  Median  Mode
A300    37  3.6   6.6     0.2
B400    82  1.9   7.7     5.0
T500    10  4.1   4.2     8.1
...     ... ...   ...     ...
```

So far my research has pointed me towards the .map function, where I would convert the 2nd table (M) into a dictionary, then map it to the column in the first table. However, I'm having trouble understanding how this works, and what I would need to write to ensure that the correct values get into the correct columns. I haven't gotten as far as writing a complete if statement for this... but I'm not sure if that's the correct direction to be going in the first place.

Any ideas or areas to research would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This thread might be of help you learn more about the `map` function:
[Using python map and other functional tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672172/using-python-map-and-other-functional-tools)

However for your specific problem, a `merge` might be a neater option.

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID_num': ['A300', 'B400', 'T500'], 'A': [37, 82, 10]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'M': [99, 37, 10, 82], 
                    'Mean': [2.3, 3.6, 4.1, 1.9],
                    'Median': [7.0, 6.6, 4.2, 7.7],
                    'Mode': [9.9, 0.2, 8.1, 5.0]})


pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on='A', right_on='M').drop('M', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  ID_num   A  Mean  Median  Mode
0   A300  37   3.6     6.6   0.2
1   B400  82   1.9     7.7   5.0
2   T500  10   4.1     4.2   8.1
```

Comment: Your method shows promise, but results in 3,308,685 rows instead of the expected 87,000. I'll be looking into pd.merge.

Comment: Would be hard to tell the cause without a reproducible example. But does column M in the second dataframe have duplicate values?  If so, the merge solution will match col A of df1 to col M of df2 multiple times, increasing the number of rows. 
On that point, if the values in column M aren't unique, a longer alternative using map would not probably still give an undesired result without a second criteria to match on