# Convert numbers string in list to number int

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, integer, converters

In Python, I want to convert all strings in a list to integers.

So if I have:

```
list1 = ['10,20,30']
```

How do I make it:

```
list1 = [10,20,30]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using python map and other functional tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672172/using-python-map-and-other-functional-tools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
list1 = [int(i) for i in list1[0].split(',')]
```

Comment: Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to define what the array contains, for how you have wrote the questions the array is:

```
0: 10,20,30
```

if your array is made of strings like that then you should make a regex to identify the numbers in every string and then convert the number into an integer.
But I think that your array is actually:

```
0: 10
1: 20
2: 30
```

In this case you would want to do:

```
for every number in the array
   make the number an integer
```

which would be

```
for num in list:
  # if the value is a string
  if type(num) == str: # just to be sure
    num = int(num)
```

In python every data type is easily changeable through `int`, `float` or `str`, but remember to assign the number after you have converted it.
`int(num)` would make a number an integer but would not actually convert it because have not stored it, you should do `num = int(num)` because those are functions that return what to want, to really understand how they works mean you should search about *dynamically typed languages* and *functions*